# Override verticalPosition property in Mat-Snack-Bar component

Tags: angular-material

I am using `mat-snack-bar` in my application and it works very well, the actual configuration is:

```js
constructor(private snackbar: MatSnackBar) { }

showNotification(message: string, buttonText: string, messageType: 'error' | 'success', 
duration?: number) {
this.snackbar.openFromComponent(NotifierComponent, {
  data: {
    message: message,
    buttonText: buttonText,
    type: messageType,
    icon: 'close'
  },
  duration: duration,
  horizontalPosition: 'center',
  verticalPosition: 'top',
  panelClass: messageType
  });
}
```

My problem is that the users of my application want that the `verticalPosition` of the snackbar to be in the middle of the screen, and I don't know how to override the property. The only possibilities are `top` and `bottom`). Have you an idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reason for only having the options `top` and `bottom` for `MatSnackBarVerticalPosition`, as can be seen [in the Angular Material API](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api#MatSnackBarVerticalPosition). They [are following Material Design](https://material.io/components/snackbars#placement), which suggests to only place it at the top or bottom of a page.

But there's a trick to accomplish what you want, although it might be a bit hacky, and that is to make use of `display: grid` on the overlay pane.

```css
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  display: grid !important;
  place-items: center !important;
}
```

The `!important` is needed to override default CSS styling to get the result you want.

[image: Snack-bar in the middle of the screen]

See [this StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksvmdg?file=src%2Fstyles.scss) for the outcome.